# General programming questions close message is disingenuous

Tags: discussion, status-completed

There have been multiple times now that I've wanted to close a question as off-topic, but refrained from doing so due to the message associated with it:

> **General programming questions** are off-topic here, but can be asked on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/about).

A prime example of this is [this recently closed question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/48607/got-indentation-error-on-this-particular-code-what-should-i-do).

That question can **not** be asked on Stack Overflow! It is vague, improperly formatted, contains spelling errors and is too localized.

Comment: Doorknob linked to the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the comments. Maybe this could be added to the message, or even used instead of the current SO link.

Comment: I think that since we can already flag questions for migration to StackOverflow, we should get rid of this close reason altogether.

Comment: This is why I typically leave a link to SO's help center in the comments even after a question has been closed with the "general programming" reason. I agree that the close reason would benefit from a change; however, the current volume of questions here is so low and the activity on SO so high that SO should be able to handle a few more off-topic questions.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

SO itself uses the following style for their close reasons:

> Questions about **general computing hardware and software** are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on [Super User](https://superuser.com/about).

and:

> Questions on **professional server- or networking-related infrastructure administration** are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve programming or programming tools. You may be able to get help on [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/about).

The "You may be able to get help..." message is nicely non-committal, as it should be for a boilerplate message — yes, you *may* be able to get an answer to your question on SO/SU/SF, *if* you describe your problem clearly in understandable English, provide a simple code example demonstrating the issue, and this time make sure that your question actually *is* on topic for the site you're asking it on.  But there's no implied guarantee in there.

So I'd suggest adopting the same non-committal phrasing here, e.g. like this:

> This site is for programming contests and challenges. **General programming questions** are off-topic here. You may be able to get help on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/about).

This phrasing avoids implying anything (positive or negative) about the question's general quality.  Of course, it you really feel that a specific off-topic question is so awful (or so excellent) that it needs something less neutral, you can always copy-paste the text as a custom close reason, and tweak it as you like.

Comment: +1. I much prefer this over my own suggestion.

Comment: I have changed the close reason according to this answer.

Answer (score 18):

I agree that this is a very common issue. I don't have hard numbers to back this up but it feels like in 75% of the cases (or more) where someone asks a "General Programming Question" it's also of very low quality, so that it would also be rejected on Stack Overflow.

At the same time, I think pointing people to SO with a fixed close vote reason is still nice and useful (whether they make their question meet SO's quality standards is their business). Therefore I propose changing the close vote reason to

> **General programming questions** are off-topic here. Your question may be better suited for [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). As Stack Overflow also has very high quality standards, please take a minute and [read their help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) prior to posting to ensure that your question is appropriate for Stack Overflow.

Comment: +1 from me. I agree with what you said, but I definitely think that message should be reworded into a bit more formal form. Also, it contains a spelling mistake ("asks").

Comment: @orlp Fixed the typo. I'll leave the rewording to someone else. ;)

Comment: While it isn't our *job* to make a high-quality SO post out of it, it certainly doesn't hurt, *if* you have the knowledge/ability/inclination to do so (I suspect many of our users have the necessary experience on SO). So while it definitely shouldn't be mandatory, it shouldn't be discouraged either.

Comment: @Geobits oh yes, I definitely don't mean to discourage, but as you say I just don't want it to make it our policy. Likewise, if it already is in good shape, flag for migration by all means.

Answer (score 6):

Usually if I see a question which is off-topic, but can't be asked as is on Stack Overflow I do the following:

- Give a **custom close reason**, and if possible state where the user *can* be redirected to (i.e. where their question *is* on topic), and
- Leave a comment saying what they would need to fix up before their question will be suitable for the site in the first point.

Answer (score 0):

I propose that our off topic message be changed to:

> This question does not appear to be about programming puzzles or challenges within the scope defined in the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

The reason is that, for an off topic question:

- "It belongs on SO." is *sometimes* true.
- "It does not belong on PPCG." is *always* true.

I would prefer that the default reason be one that is always true.